# Python: Add an entry in a file and assign an ID automatically

Tags: python, file

I'm writing a program that prompts users to do some things, and one of those is add a user by prompting user details. The file.txt is as the image below, but I'm stack on how to actually make the user ID work. The next users added should take ID numbers 5, 6, 7, and so on.

When I run the programme, the ID assigned is random. Can you please advice?
The text file is as below: (I'm a beginner in this please be detailed)

[file.txt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBtPE.png)

```
def new_user():
    file = open('file.txt', 'r+')
    lines = file.read()
    newid = len(lines)
    addUserDetail(newid)

    file.close()

def addUserDetail(newid):
    firstname = input("Please enter first name: ")
    secondname = input("Please enter surname: ")
    address1 = input("Please enter house number and street name: ")
    address2 = input("Please enter city: ")
    postcode = input("Please enter postcode: ")
    telephonenumber = input("Please enter telephone number: ")

    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    line = file.readlines()
    count = len(line)
    newcount = len(line)+1
    newline=("\n" + str(newcount) + "       " + firstname + "   " + secondname + "    " + address1 + "   " + address2 + "   " + postcode + "   " + telephonenumber)

    file = open('file.txt', 'a')
    file.write(newline)
    file.close()

while True:
    print("1 - Input for new user")
    print("2 - Close the programme")

    option = int(input("Option: "))
    if option == 1:
        new_user()
    elif option == 2:
        print("See you")
        exit(2)
    else:
        print("Your option is incorrect")
```

Comment: it's not clear what you trying to do. why pass `newid` as an argument to `addUserDetail` when you're not using it.

Comment: Could you please do add samples of your Input_file and expected output(if applicable) in text form with CODE TAGS in your question, links or images for inputs are not encourages on SO, kindly do edit your question and let us know then.

Comment: You aren't using `newid`. If you did, its counting the total number of characters in the file, not the lines. In `new_user` it should be `lines = file.readlines()`. That would explain the user id growing faster than expected. But from the code I see, `newcount = len(line)+1` is close. It would skip 2 - you'd get 1 for an empty file, but once you write `"\nsome stuff", that's 2 lines and you'd get 3.

Comment: If you use MySQL for your user storage, you can use the `AUTO_INCREMENT`attribute on your `id` field to automatically assign the next ID.

Comment: Caught the error @tdelaney Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I am not entirely sure if I understood your problem correctly, I am assuming that you would like to use `newid` in `addUserDetail` before writing the values back.

The `newid` inside the `new_user` function isn't actually taking an arbitrary value. It equals the number of characters in the file. This is because of the `file.read()` returns type `str`. This can be fixed by using the `readlines()` function.

The code for the same is as follows:

```
def new_user():
    file = open('file.txt', 'r+')
    lines = [i.strip() for i in file.readlines()]
    newid = len(lines)
    addUserDetail(newid)

    file.close()

def addUserDetail(newid):
    firstname = input("Please enter first name: ")
    secondname = input("Please enter surname: ")
    address1 = input("Please enter house number and street name: ")
    address2 = input("Please enter city: ")
    postcode = input("Please enter postcode: ")
    telephonenumber = input("Please enter telephone number: ")

    file = open('file.txt', 'r')
    line = file.readlines()
    
    newline = ("\n" + str(newid+1) + "       " + firstname + "   " + secondname + "    " + address1 + "   " + address2 + "   " + postcode + "   " + telephonenumber)

    file = open('file.txt', 'a')
    file.write(newline)
    file.close()

while True:
    print("1 - Input for new user")
    print("2 - Close the programme")

    option = int(input("Option: "))
    if option == 1:
        new_user()
    elif option == 2:
        print("See you")
        exit(2)
    else:
        print("Your option is incorrect")
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an example for leveraging comma-separated-value (CSV) files for holding your data. This can be better than simply writing data with spaces because its easier to read back later. What do you do when the address itself has spaces?

Python has a handy `csv` module that can help with the details. So, here is your problem reworked. This isn't exactly the answer, but an alternate option.

```
import csv
import os

def new_user():
    # removed id generation... let add the called routine that updated
    # the database do that
    addUserDetail()

def addUserDetail():
    firstname = input("Please enter first name: ")
    secondname = input("Please enter surname: ")
    address1 = input("Please enter house number and street name: ")
    address2 = input("Please enter city: ")
    postcode = input("Please enter postcode: ")
    telephonenumber = input("Please enter telephone number: ")

    if not os.path.exists('file.txt'):
        with open('file.txt', 'w'):
            pass

    with open('file.txt', 'r+') as file:
        user_id = len(file.readlines()) + 1
        writer = csv.writer(file)
        writer.writerow([user_id, firstname, secondname, address1, 
            address2, postcode, telephonenumber])
    file.close()

while True:
    print("1 - Input for new user")
    print("2 - Close the programme")

    option = int(input("Option: "))
    if option == 1:
        new_user()
    elif option == 2:
        print("See you")
        exit(2)
    else:
        print("Your option is incorrect")
```

The output from adding 2 users is

```
1,Jen,Dixon,1 A Street,Big City,99999,111-111-111
2,Bradly,Thompson,99 Elm,Small Town,222,9999
```

Comment: Unfortunately this one doesn't work, it appends the data input on the last line of the code and a new user ID is not generated. I sorted the problem by implementing the new_user() function.

Comment: It writes one line per data record. The difference is that yours starts wtih a new line (leaving line 1 as a blank link) and this ends with a newline (traditional CSV). The first column is the ID, 1 and 2 in this example.